# How to inject a DAO objecct to another DAO class in Spring 3

Tags: spring

In my application I am using Spring3 MVC framework. I have a DAO class TestDAO1.java in which I need a method getArticleList() which is declared in TestDAO2.java class.

As per my knowledge, we can inject Service layer  objects to controllers and DAOs to Service layer.
But can we inject a DAO object to a DAO class ?

Here I want to inject TestDAO2 class object to TestDAO1.java class. So I can use getArticleList() method.  How can I do it ?

Is it a  right way OR standard to inject a DAO to DAO ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Here I want to inject TestDAO2 class object to TestDAO1.java class. So I can use getArticleList() method. How can I do it ?

the same way as you inject one into controller - e.g. using `@Autowired` annotation:

```
public class TestDAO2 {
    @Autowired private TestDAO1 dao1;
    ....
```

there's no difference whether injected object is a service or another DAO.

> Is it a right way OR standard to inject a DAO to DAO ?

in general: **no**. This situation indicates there *may* be some design issues in your model or DAO. perhaps your `TestDAO1` is doing too much? try moving this functionality into a **service that uses both DAOs**!

Comment: +1 for not only addressing OP's question but also thinking one level deeper (as to a possible design issue).

Comment: @mantrid : Thanks for the reply. DAO injection works fine with Autowired annotation. And I agree that there is some design issue with my app which forced me to inject a DAO into a DAO. But for the purpose of code re-usability, I tried to use functionality which is declared into some other DAO. As per my app design, for "each" entity, I am creating a new DAO class which CRUD methods.So as per my view, this is DB design issue. I think, I should create DB design more optimized way so such cases should not occur.